# Inherit multiple base classes with the same inherited method-name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

NOTE: I'm fairly new to C# .Net MVC and Entity Framework, and am working on an existing project. In this project I have the following class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("name=SQLAzureConnection")
    {
    }

    ... // Some IDbSet properties

    ... // Some methods
}
```

and the following interface:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    ... // Some properties

    ... // Some methods
    void Dispose();
}
```

In one of my methods I use:

```
using(IMyDbContext usingDb = MvcApplication.dbContext())
{
    // Some query with usingDb
}
```

(With `MvcApplication.dbContext()` being a delegate (Func), which is instantiated like this in my MvcApplication`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    // Delegate Func to create a new IMyDbContext instance
    public static Func<IMyDbContext> dbContext;
    public static MyDbContext dbContextInit()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    }

    ... // Some other fields

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        dbContext = dbContextInit();
    }
}
```

the reason I have this delegate is for short-lived DbContext and being able to use it in my UnitTests.)

Since an object in the using should be `Disposable`, I modified my interface to the following:

```
public interface IMyDbContext : IDisposable
{
    ... // Some properties

    ... // Some methods
    void Dispose();
}
```

Everything works, except I get the following warning:

```
'MyNamespace.Model.IMyDbContext.Dispose()' hides inherited member
'System.IDisposable.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

So does this mean I should use: `new void Dispose();` instead of `void Dispose()`? The only reason I made it inherit `IDisposable` is so I can use it in the `using`. So I guess the `new`-keyword so it will use the `DbContext.Dispose()` is the correct way of handling this? Or am I doing something wrong?

I've also read I could just use a `try-finally` instead of the `using`, so I use `usingDb.Dispose()` myself in the `finally-case`. Still, I prefer inheriting `IDisposable` myself instead of that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of YOUR `dispose` in your inteface because you are already getting it from `IDisposable` so just change your interface to this:

```
public interface IMyDbContext : IDisposable
{
    ... // Some properties
}
```

This is because you are making your `IMyDbContext` disposable already with `IDisposable` therefore you don't need to explicitly add again. The compile is warning you that you are doing something odd by having two `Dispose` without explicitly telling users why.

**Summary: Just remove it and you are golden!**

Answer (score 0):

If `IDisposable.Dispose` and `IMyDbContext.Dispose` means the same thing, just do the following:

```
public interface IMyDbContext : IDisposable
{
   ... // Some properties
   // You get Dispose() from `IDisposable`
}
```

If `IDisposable.Dispose` and `IMyDbContext.Dispose` means the different thing(different implementation required) use Explicit interface implementation

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("name=SQLAzureConnection")
    {
    }

    IMyDbContext.Dispose() // Implement it via explicit implementation
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't need to implement it because it is already implemented in DbContext.

Comment: @RobEpstein Am sorry, I'm not familiar with entity framework. I gave a general answer

Comment: No worries and no slight intended. Just wanting to ensure the user was aware. ;)